# Does the Bluetooth/Google Now "Initializing" bug exist on Razr Maxx HD?

Tags: bluetooth, 4.1-jelly-bean, motorola-droid-razr, google-now

There is a pretty severe, [widespread Android Jellybean bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35737) that causes Google Now voice search to not work over bluetooth audio (it gets stuck saying "Initializing").  I've personally dealt with this on a Galaxy S3 and a Galaxy Note 2, both running 4.1.1.

I'm curious whether the Razr Maxx HD has this bug - is there any credible information on which phones are affected by this bug?  Or can anyone vouch from experience whether this is a bug on the Razr Maxx HD as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verified that this bug does indeed exist on the Razr Maxx HD (running 4.1.1)